# "Repeat as header row at the top of each page" causes a page break before table

Tags: microsoft-word, accessibility

I have an issue with a table in Microsoft Word with a document that has two tables in it. The document was created on a Mac, but I have also tested it on a PC with the same results. Both tables are span more than one page vertically. For accessibility and usability purposes I am trying to set the header row in the table so that it repeats across both pages that it appears on. I am doing this using the setting:
Table Properties > Row > Repeat as header row at the top of each page (Checked)

For one of the tables this works great, but for the other one, when I set this option the table acts as if a page break was added before an it moves to start on the next page leaving a large white space before it. I have played with all kinds of settings and compared the settings of the two tables, but without any luck.

The "Repeat as header row at the top of each page" functionality works great - but I can't figure out what is causing the page break or how I can get rid of it. Any ideas are appreciated - I am also happy to share a link to the document.

Comment: This question would likely be better asked in the Microsoft Community where you would quickly receive an answer. There are too many possible options. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word ---- **My guess is that it involves the paragraph formatting in your table cells "keep with next" setting, but that is just a guess.**